# Without adding cross origin code on service side how to solve cross origin issue?

Tags: java, php, angular, laravel, api

Without adding cross origin code on service side language. it is possible to solve cross origin issue angular 7 to Java API or Laravel (PHP).

With out adding below code.

**For Java:**

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            // response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**For Laravel:**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the CORS [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

So, if you really do not want to set CORS headers on your API server, you need to make sure that the API server has the same protocol, host and domain as your angular website.

Otherwise, if it's just for dev/test purposes, you could try using angular's [proxy server](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: Means we need host both code on same server right? @David

Comment: It needs to be the same protocol, domain and port. So as long as you've got the right infrastructure for it (e.g. load balancer), the API and frontend code do not need to be on the same server.